# Grid layout using masonry and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a page which looks somewhat like this on desktops
[image]

And it will have a one column layout for mobile devices. With the image first, then the long text, then the advertisers, then the comments.

Problem is, a lot of negative spaces in between. I want a cascading grid layout, like what masonry does and also responsive resizing of elements which is easy using bootstrap columns. I know that this can be done using a lot of media queries, but I wanted to know if there is a way to combine bootstrap and masonry to achieve the effect with minimum effort. Just using both the classes for bootsrap and masonry is not working as this is what I have until now:

[image]

As you can see, there is a huge negative space. Clearfix didn't work too.
Here is my code right now:

```html
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row grid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-primary grid-item">
    <img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1307a.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-info grid-item">
    <p>
    Ricotta monterey jack cow. Paneer cheese and biscuits everyone loves fromage frais monterey jack caerphilly camembert de normandie lancashire. Danish fontina everyone loves pepper jack lancashire hard cheese bocconcini edam cheese and wine. Cheese and wine manchego rubber cheese blue castello blue castello rubber cheese queso cheesy grin. Say cheese pecorino smelly cheese halloumi cheesy feet cheese slices ricotta croque monsieur. Blue castello parmesan caerphilly mozzarella bavarian bergkase say cheese red leicester macaroni cheese. Edam cheese strings camembert de normandie cheese and wine red leicester gouda cream cheese everyone loves. Cheddar who moved my cheese manchego chalk and cheese boursin lancashire.
    </p>
    <p>
    Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese. Taleggio squirty cheese croque monsieur macaroni cheese fondue cheddar bavarian bergkase st. agur blue cheese. St. agur blue cheese cottage cheese swiss everyone loves swiss dolcelatte babybel monterey jack. Gouda monterey jack fromage feta taleggio cheese triangles parmesan cheddar. Rubber cheese fromage frais stinking bishop boursin red leicester camembert de normandie fromage frais gouda. Halloumi ricotta port-salut hard cheese squirty cheese cheese slices brie.
    </p>
    <p>
    Babybel cheese on toast feta. Ricotta dolcelatte mozzarella cheese and wine goat rubber cheese cheesy feet cheesy feet. Boursin stinking bishop cheesecake bocconcini mascarpone cut the cheese bocconcini cut the cheese. Hard cheese fromage caerphilly cheeseburger cheese on toast emmental bocconcini bocconcini. Ricotta cheese strings cheese and wine camembert de normandie cut the cheese feta babybel bocconcini. Cauliflower cheese lancashire parmesan everyone loves cheese and wine cauliflower cheese mascarpone when the cheese comes out everybody's happy. Fromage cheese and biscuits.
    </p>
    <p>
    Mozzarella queso emmental. Queso manchego gouda blue castello blue castello macaroni cheese mozzarella roquefort. Who moved my cheese cauliflower cheese caerphilly mozzarella cut the cheese the big cheese say cheese rubber cheese. Cheeseburger mozzarella emmental paneer blue castello taleggio who moved my cheese cream cheese. Croque monsieur cheese triangles cheddar halloumi cheesecake goat queso fromage. Airedale who moved my cheese cheesy grin cheese and biscuits pepper jack chalk and cheese cheese slices.
    </p>
    <p>
    Squirty cheese mascarpone lancashire. Cottage cheese mozzarella st. agur blue cheese squirty cheese brie pecorino danish fontina smelly cheese. Babybel cheese and wine bavarian bergkase gouda bocconcini stinking bishop macaroni cheese gouda. Lancashire cheese strings chalk and cheese cheesecake mozzarella monterey jack the big cheese monterey jack. Goat who moved my cheese cheese on toast danish fontina pepper jack gouda queso the big cheese. Airedale monterey jack airedale cauliflower cheese.
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-success grid-item">
    Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-danger grid-item">
    Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about Flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: What is the actual need to get involved with Masonry here? It looks to me that it could be done with plain Bootstrap columns?

Comment: I tried with bootstrap columns only, but it didn't work out. There is no real compulsion to use masonry, I just want this to work @mayersdesign

Comment: I was actually trying to do it with minimum css apart from styling @DanEpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution you want with masonry. And there are more technique to clear that white-space.

**Remove & Added:** remove clear div and img width add bootstrap default img-responsive.

**Important**:  bootstrap grid system each row contain 12 col.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.grid').masonry({ 
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.1.1/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row grid">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-primary grid-item">
   <img src="https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/large/heic1307a.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
   Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-info grid-item">
   <p> Ricotta monterey jack cow. Paneer cheese and biscuits everyone loves fromage frais monterey jack caerphilly camembert de normandie lancashire. Danish fontina everyone loves pepper jack lancashire hard cheese bocconcini edam cheese and wine. Cheese and wine manchego rubber cheese blue castello blue castello rubber cheese queso cheesy grin. Say cheese pecorino smelly cheese halloumi cheesy feet cheese slices ricotta croque monsieur. Blue castello parmesan caerphilly mozzarella bavarian bergkase say cheese red leicester macaroni cheese. Edam cheese strings camembert de normandie cheese and wine red leicester gouda cream cheese everyone loves. Cheddar who moved my cheese manchego chalk and cheese boursin lancashire.
   </p>
   <p>Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese. Taleggio squirty cheese croque monsieur macaroni cheese fondue cheddar bavarian bergkase st. agur blue cheese. St. agur blue cheese cottage cheese swiss everyone loves swiss dolcelatte babybel monterey jack. Gouda monterey jack fromage feta taleggio cheese triangles parmesan cheddar. Rubber cheese fromage frais stinking bishop boursin red leicester camembert de normandie fromage frais gouda. Halloumi ricotta port-salut hard cheese squirty cheese cheese slices brie. 
   </p>
   <p>Babybel cheese on toast feta. Ricotta dolcelatte mozzarella cheese and wine goat rubber cheese cheesy feet cheesy feet. Boursin stinking bishop cheesecake bocconcini mascarpone cut the cheese bocconcini cut the cheese. Hard cheese fromage caerphilly cheeseburger cheese on toast emmental bocconcini bocconcini. Ricotta cheese strings cheese and wine camembert de normandie cut the cheese feta babybel bocconcini. Cauliflower cheese lancashire parmesan everyone loves cheese and wine cauliflower cheese mascarpone when the cheese comes out everybody's happy. Fromage cheese and biscuits.
   </p>
   <p>Mozzarella queso emmental. Queso manchego gouda blue castello blue castello macaroni cheese mozzarella roquefort. Who moved my cheese cauliflower cheese caerphilly mozzarella cut the cheese the big cheese say cheese rubber cheese. Cheeseburger mozzarella emmental paneer blue castello taleggio who moved my cheese cream cheese. Croque monsieur cheese triangles cheddar halloumi cheesecake goat queso fromage. Airedale who moved my cheese cheesy grin cheese and biscuits pepper jack chalk and cheese cheese slices.
   </p>
   <p>Squirty cheese mascarpone lancashire. Cottage cheese mozzarella st. agur blue cheese squirty cheese brie pecorino danish fontina smelly cheese. Babybel cheese and wine bavarian bergkase gouda bocconcini stinking bishop macaroni cheese gouda. Lancashire cheese strings chalk and cheese cheesecake mozzarella monterey jack the big cheese monterey jack. Goat who moved my cheese cheese on toast danish fontina pepper jack gouda queso the big cheese. Airedale monterey jack airedale cauliflower cheese.
   </p>
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-success grid-item">
    Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bg-danger grid-item">
   Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.Boursin stilton caerphilly. Cheddar macaroni cheese fromage frais macaroni cheese cheesecake halloumi emmental smelly cheese.
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```